# 2D c++ array with sum

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

professor gave me task to write program that generates 2D array using function random and then if other function (that is void type) I should find row with biggest sum and index of that row. Here is my code I know I made mistake in void function but I don't know how to write that function if possible help... Any comment would be great help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void najred(int a[5][5], int *s)
{
    int i;  
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        *s += a[i][j];
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[5][5], i, j, s;
    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % (82);
        }
    }

    printf("ARRAY :\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    najred(a, &s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> function (that is void type) l should find row with biggest sum and
>   index of that row

It is a bad function declaration. It would be much better if the function simply would return the row with maximum sum. Having the row you can always calculate the index.

I would define the function the following way

```
int ( * )[5] najred( int ( *a )[5], size_t n )
{
   int ( *max_row )[5] = a;

   if ( n != 0 )
   {
      int max_sum = std::accumulate( *a, *a + 5, 0 );

      for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
      {
         int sum = std::accumulate( *( a + i ), *( a + i ) + 5, 0 );
         if ( max_sum < sum )
         {
            max_sum = sum;
            max_row = a + i;
         }
      }
   }

   return ( max_row );
}
```

Or you can use standard algorithm `std::max_element` for your two-dimensional array with a lambda-expression.

If the function has to have return type void then it could look the following way

```
void najred( int ( * &a )[5], size_t n )
{
   int ( *max_row )[5] = a;

   if ( n != 0 )
   {
      int max_sum = std::accumulate( *a, *a + 5, 0 );

      for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
      {
         int sum = std::accumulate( *( a + i ), *( a + i ) + 5, 0 );
         if ( max_sum < sum )
         {
            max_sum = sum;
            max_row = a + i;
         }
      }
   }

   a = max_row;
}
```

The function can be called the following way

```
int ( *p )[5] = a;

najred( p, 5 );
```

and the index is calculated after the function call as

```
int index = p - a;
```

Comment: well l know it would be simmplier but say that to my proffesor...he pointed it out that it has to be void function

Comment: thx but my c++ compiler doenst allow half of the things you used...another great side of my professor...l cant even use normal c++

Comment: You should clarify yourself whether you use C or C++. I do not understand what means "do not use normal C++". It is a nonsense.

Comment: l use c++ but  professor gave us some sort of school version that is  outdated and limited so l cant  do half of the programs like  all you guys do...anyway thx for the  effort and help :)

Comment: If you are speaking about std::acumulate then you can write the sum of a row yourself.

Comment: facepalm -.- l didnt know that  well l made some changes and now l dont know how to call function....

Answer (score 0):

In your `najred` function, you need to keep track of the maximum sum and the row it was found on.

```
  int max_sum = INT_MIN;  // Mininum value for int, see <limits>
  int row_of_max = -1;
  int row_sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    row_sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
      row_sum += a[i][j];
    }
    if (row_sum > max_sum)
    {
      row_of_max = i;
      max_sum = row_sum;
    }
  }
```

Returning the value **and** the index are left to the OP.

Comment: lol now lm stuck with OP cant find where l make mistake   since it shows radom    number instad of sum row...thx anyway